# About xymtx-ps.sty file

Tags: xymtex

At the time I’m learning how to use XyMTeX services, it offers to graphic chemical structures with a nice. I knew about `\usepackage{xymtex}`, however, this is not enough clear to perform some structures, some of them look rough at the end. I knew I could use `\usepackage{xymtexps}` but I don’t get satisfactory results. It simple does not compile.

I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xymtex}%XyMTeX plain
%\usepackage{xymtexpdf}%XyMTeX for PDF ... dvipdfmx ... .pdf
\usepackage{xymtexps}%XyMTeX for PostScript ...
\usepackage{txfonts}%Times Roman
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\let\substfontsize=\small%changing font size
\bzdrh{2==\ethylene{1==C;2==C}{1==H;2==H;3==(yl);4==H}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I get `File 'xymtx-ps.sty' not found. \endinput` and it does not work. Please some help.
I have that file on my Desktop but I don’t know what to do with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XyMTeX has recently been updated. What version of `xymtex.sty` have you got? On TeX Live 2013 it is version 5.01 dated March 10, 2013.

Comment: fwiw, it also seems up-to-date in the miktex distribution

Comment: i'm concerned about "I have that file on my Desktop" ... the file needs to be installed in the "proper" place in the miktex texmf tree.  if your miktex/texlive was up-to-date, it would already have the file; perhaps you might try updating it.  what version of tex are you running?  whatever, it looks out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with an up-to-date TeXLive 2013. Running in a terminal

```
voss@shania:~> kpsewhich xymtx-ps.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xymtex/xymtxps/xymtx-ps.sty
```

I get the directory where `xymtx-ps.sty` is installed. However, if you are using MikTeX then go into the MikTeX package manager and look if that package is installed. My output when running your example with `xelatex`:

[image]